# Условие отправки транзакционных emails

Tags: php, email, magento

Есть аукцион на Magento. По окончанию аукциона, пользователям, что принимали участие в аукционе, на почту приходит письмо о результатах. Победителю - одни шаблон, тем кто проиграл - другой. 

Не все пользователи, что подали заявку, принимают участие в аукционе - только те, кого подтвердил администратор. 
И вот проблема состоит в том что письмо о том, что пользователь проиграл, приходит даже тем кто не был допущен к аукциону.
Вот код ответственный за отправку этих писем:

```
foreach($collection as $customer){
                    $customer->setData('name', $customer->getName());
                    if($members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId())->getId() != $bet->getMemberId()) {
                        /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Member $member */
                        $member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());

                        /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Resource_Bet_Collection $memberBetCollection */
                        $memberBetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('custom_auction/bet_collection');
                        $memberBetCollection->addFieldToFilter('member_id', $member->getId());
                        $memberBetCollection->setOrder('bet_id');

                        $memberBet = $memberBetCollection->getFirstItem();

                        $templateId = 3;
                        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer $mailer */
                        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

                        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info $emailInfo */
                        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                        $emailInfo->addTo($customer->getData('email'), $customer->getName());
                        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

                        // Set all required params and send emails
                        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
                        $mailer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
                        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                                'customer'  => $customer,
                                'product'   => $product,
                                'bet'       => $memberBet
                            )
                        );
                        $mailer->send();
                    }else{
                        /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Member $member */
                        $member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
                        $member->setData('status', 3);
                        $member->save();

                        $templateId = 4;
                        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer $mailer */
                        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

                        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info $emailInfo */
                        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                        $emailInfo->addTo($customer->getData('email'), $customer->getName());
                        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

                        // Set all required params and send emails
                        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
                        $mailer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
                        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                                'customer'  => $customer,
                                'product'   => $product,
                                'bet'       => $bet
                            )
                        );
                        $mailer->send();
                    }
```

Я так понимаю что эта часть кода выбирает победителя (учасника со статусом 3) и отправляет ему письмо победителя (шаблон с id 3).

```
$member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
                            $member->setData('status', 3);
                            $member->save();

                            $templateId = 4;
```

Можно ли так же поставить выборку для проигравших?
Типа:

```
/** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Member $member */
                        $member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
                        $member->setData('status', 2);
                        $member->save();

                        /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Resource_Bet_Collection $memberBetCollection */
                        $memberBetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('custom_auction/bet_collection');
                        $memberBetCollection->addFieldToFilter('member_id', $member->getId());
                        $memberBetCollection->setOrder('bet_id');

                        $memberBet = $memberBetCollection->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо в коде, начинающимся с "foreach($collection as $customer){" в конце не хватает закрывающей "}"

Вероятнее всего проблема в том, как формируется коллекция $collection, так как письмо получают все участники коллекции. Вы перебираете всех customer из коллекции $collection и отправляете им письмо по шаблону, который зависит от того, совпадает ли id участника коллекции $members с $bet->getMemberId() или нет. Т.е. если в коллекцию $collection попали пользователи не одобренные администратором, они всё равно получат сообщение, так как у вас нет проверки, что почту получают только участники $members.

Так же хочу обратить ваше внимание, что в код:

```
$member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
```

И код, касающийся формирования письма, можно вынести за условие, чтобы не плодить сущностей. Также можно добавить в цикл проверку на принадлежность коллекции $members участника коллекции $collection, выйдет что-то подобное:

```
/** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Member $member */
$member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
if(!$member->getId()) { continue;}
if($member->getId() != $bet->getMemberId()) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Но разумнее ограничить коллекцию $collection на этапе подготовки, добавив фильтры, отсекающие пользователей, не одобренных администратором.

$templateId можно извлечь из базы, обратившись по полю Code, не привязываясь строго к фактическому Id template`а

```
$templateId = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('Код')->getTemplateId();
```

Коды ваших template`ов можно посмотреть admin`ке в разделе "Transactional Emails" или c помощью запроса к базе:

```
SELECT template_id, template_code FROM core_email_template WHERE template_id IN (3,4);
```

Статусы удобно объявлять константами в файле модели:

```
class Custom_Auction_Model_Member extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    const CUSTOMER_WIN_BET = 3;
    ...
}
```

Это нагляднее. Так проще потом, спустя какое-то время, рабираться в логике модуля и что значит каждый статус. Для записи значения статуса, можно использовать короткое обращение $member->setStatus(Значение), если вы не имеете ничего против magic methods :)

```
}else{
    $member->setStatus(Mage::getModel('custom_auction/member')::CUSTOMER_WIN_BET);
    $member->save();

    $templateId = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('TemplateCode')->getTemplateId();
```

Для чего строка:

```
$customer->setData('name', $customer->getName());
```

в приведенном коде не ясно. Вы берете из Data поле $data['name'] c помощью запроса $customer->getName() и записываете его обрано в $data['name'] на тоже место. Полагаю это ошибка.

В результате, если посчитать, что статус вынесен константой в модель, а проверка принадлежности пользователя коллекции $members всё-таки происходит в цикле, получится что-то подобное:

```
try{
    foreach($collection as $customer){
        /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Member $member */
        $member = $members->getItemByColumnValue('customer_id', $customer->getId());
        if(!$member->getId()) { continue;}

         /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer $mailer */
        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info $emailInfo */
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($customer->getData('email'), $customer->getName());

        /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info $emailInfo */
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
        $mailer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        if($member->getId() != $bet->getMemberId()) {

            /** @var Custom_Auction_Model_Resource_Bet_Collection $memberBetCollection */
            $memberBetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('custom_auction/bet_collection');
            $memberBetCollection->addFieldToFilter('member_id', $member->getId());
            $memberBetCollection->setOrder('bet_id');

            $memberBet = $memberBetCollection->getFirstItem();

            $templateCode = 'TemplateCodeForId_3';
        }else{
            $member->setStatus(Mage::getModel('custom_auction/member')::CUSTOMER_WIN_BET);
            $member->save();

            $memberBet = $bet;
            $templateCode = 'TemplateCodeForId_4';
        }

        $mailer->setTemplateId(Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateCode)->getTemplateId());
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'customer'  => $customer,
                'product'   => $product,
                'bet'       => $memberBet
            )
        );
        $mailer->send();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Осторожнее! Код я не тестировал. Удачи вам с Magento!

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.